# Some correction about jquery and iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, greasemonkey

I create a simple greasemonkey script, it's attached new menu on a page, when clicked it will show the iframe, I want to make sure that when I click the menu the iframe has already fully loaded, so I created this

```
$('<div id="googleBar"><iframe id="googleBarFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&amp;answer=1053549"></iframe></div>').insertBefore('#pagelet_welcome_box');

$('#googleBarFrame').load(function() 
{
    $('#pageNav').prepend('<li id="navShare" class="topNavLink middleLink"><a accesskey="1" >Google+ Share</a></li>');
});

//This not working
var toggle = false;
$('#navShare').click(function() {
    if (toggle) {
        $("#googleBar").animate({
        height: '30px',
        }, 500 );
    toggle = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#googleBar").animate({
        height: '250px',
        }, 500 );
    toggle = true;
    }
});
```

but that's not working, and this my working script but without ability to detect iframe has loaded

```
$('#pageNav').prepend('<li id="navShare" class="topNavLink middleLink"><a accesskey="1" >Google+ Share</a></li>');

$('<div id="googleBar"><iframe id="googleBarFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py"></iframe></div>').insertBefore('#pagelet_welcome_box');

var toggle = false;
$('#navShare').click(function() {
    if (toggle) {
        $("#googleBar").animate({
        height: '30px',
        }, 500 );
    toggle = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#googleBar").animate({
        height: '250px',
        }, 500 );
    toggle = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... event handling in greasemonkey isn't easy. If you want to bind callback to the load event for iframe, you should try something like that

```
function callback() {
    $('#pageNav').prepend('<li id="navShare" class="topNavLink middleLink"><a accesskey="1" >Google+ Share</a></li>');
}
document.getElementById('googleBarFrame').addEventListener('load', callback, false);
```

I didn't test that so it may not work becouse of something silly (for example i'm not sure if event name passed in "addEventListener" is 'load' or 'onload').

This method (addEventListener) worked for me with "click" event in greasemonkey so it may also work with load event.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i try both ....addEventListener('load',... and ....addEventListener('onload',... and both not working.

Comment: hmm ... make sure that addEventListener is called after googleBarFrame is created in DOM and before it is loaded